# Horizontal scrolling website content

Tags: html, css, horizontal-scrolling

My objective is to make a website for my portfolio.
I have a div for the menu that wanted to be on top of another div that works as a container for all of my images. The images have to fill 100% height of the browser.
The problem is, that I wanted my website to scroll horizontally and when I start to add content, as soon as the width goes over the 100% of the browser window the new image goes under the first image making it scroll horizontally.

What can I do to correct this?

CSS

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

#main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#menu {
    width: 200px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    overflow: scroll;
    z-index: 2;
}

#img {
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML layout you're using? Also, you may want to use a div id different from '#img' since that's close to the html property.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the width from your #main tag. As soon as an element hits that 100% it's going to move down to the next line.